# Incrementally copying text to the clipboard using the mouse

Tags: emacs, copy, mouse

I would like to set up the mouse in Emacs so that it incrementally adds the text selected with the mouse to the contents of the clipboard.

For example, if the shift key is kept pressed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Try to provide a step-by-step description of what you want to do and what you would expect to see at each step. In particular, what do you mean by "incrementally adds" text to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

By default copying text in Emacs sends it to the kill-ring and clipboard likewise. The latter is a X-windows-thing, not from Emacs.

When appending, rather do that inside Emacs.
With a second step update the first entry of the kill-ring resp. the clipboard.